# Email attachment in Oracle BI Publisher?

Tags: oracle, bi-publisher

The send button in BI Publisher (Oracle Business Intelligence Publisher Release 10.1.3.4) will send the generated report into the body of an email. We have to manually key in email parameters like to, cc, etc.

Is there a way we could attach a document say pdf here (without bursting)? I am sure we can burst attachments with bursting. Kindly tell me if there is any other way, we could attach a document while sending the report as email by clicking on the **send button**

Comment: What is the reason not to use bursting?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Send`. You can run the report and have it sent as an attachment in the email. In order to do this click on the `Schedule` link on the top right hand corner while you are in the report.

[image]

This will take you to a page where in the `Time` section (see below) you can either run immediately or schedule it to run automatically daily/weekly/monthly, and then in the `Delivery` section specify your To, CC, Subject etc. and then Click on "Submit".

[image]

This way your report will be emailed as an attachment based on your template type (i.e. as PDF if your template is rtf, as Excel if your template is Excel)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want the report to be in the body part, using the **send** button does that. I need to attach a document to the email,is it possible? or is there any other possibility to send a report to the body of the email and also attach a document(atleast static document) to it?

Comment: I don't think having both in one email is possible. There are very less reports that a user would want to see in an email body plus there could be formatting issues as well if the email goes to different mail servers i.e. Domino, Exchange etc. You could have two emails one with the attachment and one with report in body, but why would you do that!

Comment: Thanks for your response.We tried sending a report which is in japanese as an email body using the send button.The Japanese characters which are properly shown in HTML output are not getting displayed properly in email output. We tried changing the encoding but of no use. We are getting text like ** å•¥å ´æ¤œæŸ»ãƒ¬ãƒãƒ¼ãƒˆã‚’ãƒ¬ãƒ“ãƒ¥ãƒ¼ã **The encoding used in BIP server is UTF8. Any help ?